# What does the asterisk mean after a filename when you type `ls -l`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls

I've done an `ls -l` inside a directory, and my files are displaying like this :

```
james@nevada:~/development/tools/android-sdk-linux_86/tools$ ll
total 9512
drwxr-xr-x 3 james james    4096 2010-05-07 19:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 james james    4096 2010-08-21 20:43 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james  341773 2010-05-07 19:47 adb*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    3636 2010-05-07 19:47 android*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    2382 2010-05-07 19:47 apkbuilder*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    3265 2010-05-07 19:47 ddms*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james   89032 2010-05-07 19:47 dmtracedump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    1940 2010-05-07 19:47 draw9patch*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james 6886136 2010-05-07 19:47 emulator*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james  478199 2010-05-07 19:47 etc1tool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    1987 2010-05-07 19:47 hierarchyviewer*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james   23044 2010-05-07 19:47 hprof-conv*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    1939 2010-05-07 19:47 layoutopt*
drwxr-xr-x 4 james james    4096 2010-05-07 19:48 lib/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james   16550 2010-05-07 19:47 mksdcard*
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  205851 2010-05-07 19:48 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james      33 2010-05-07 19:47 source.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james 1447936 2010-05-07 19:47 sqlite3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james    3044 2010-05-07 19:47 traceview*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james  187965 2010-05-07 19:47 zipalign*
```

What does that asterisk mean?

I'm also unable to run a particular file, as follows:

```
james@nevada:~/development/tools/android-sdk-linux_86/tools$ ./emulator 
bash: ./emulator: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT** : I'm trying to get Eclipse to use `emulator`, but it keeps complaining the files does not exist, yet it is here?

Comment: All files are marked as executable on NTFS partitions.

Comment: @Smile4ever that's simply not true. It depends on how you've mounted the partition and by default it's mounted as all-executable. The same applies to FAT and other non-Unix partitions. However you can also store Unix permissions on NTFS because it's POSIX compatible https://askubuntu.com/q/86959/253474 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11757/44425

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You can mount your partition differently, yes. But by default it's mounted as executable on most Linux distributions. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has already explained about the `*`](https://superuser.com/questions/178786/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-after-a-filename-if-you-do-ls-l/178789#178789):

> It means that the file is executable. A classifier is shown when -F is
>   passed to ls via the command line or otherwise.

As for the executable-looking `emulator` that you can't actually execute, this can happen when the dynamic loader requested by `emulator` doesn't exist. You can check what kind of file `emulator` is with the command `file emulator`, and check what dynamic loader and libraries it needs with `ldd emulator` (any line showing “not found” is something you need to install).

Given the name of the directory and the size of the file, `emulator` is probably a Linux x86 binary. I suspect you have an amd64 system. If so, you need to install a runtime environment for 32-bit applications; on Ubuntu, you need the `ia32-libs` package (and perhaps also `ia32-libs-gtk`).

You could also get this error message for a script whose interpreter as indicated in the `#!` line doesn't exist.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give what you suggested a shot. Only thing that confuses me is that I had this running yesterday, and since then have only restarted... :S

Comment: `-bash: ./badshebang: /bin/xyzzy: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 92):

It means that the file is executable. A *classifier* is shown when `-F` is passed to `ls` via the command line or otherwise.

Answer (score 50):

From `info ls`:

```
`-F'
`--classify'
`--indicator-style=classify'
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append `*'.  The file
     type indicators are `/' for directories, `@' for symbolic links,
     `|' for FIFOs, `=' for sockets, `>' for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.
```

Answer (score 29):

Ubuntu (12.04, and probably other versions as well) includes the following setting by default:

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

And as others have explained, `-F` is responsible for the asterisk.

IPython automatically uses the `F` flag under the hood (by default), so just entering `ls` will produce the effect you're seeing there.

Edit: by the way, you are stating you're running `ls -l`, running `ll` may not be the same at all.

Comment: A fun trick you can do in Bash is type the alias'd command (e.g. "ll") and press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[e].  It'll expand the alias so you can see what it's actually processing.  (you might have to press it a few times to fully expand)

Answer (score 14):

As several others have mentioned, the `-F` option to `ls` will flag executables with the asterisk.  You don't have a `-F` in your command line, but it is likely that `ls` has been aliased.  You can check for aliases in your shell of choice (in bash, use the built-in command `alias` to list the aliases), or escape the `ls` command with a backslash to disable aliasing.