# java application can't execute file stored in /tmp

Tags: linux, java

I am running into trouble with a java program, which attempts to write files to the `/tmp` directory on Ubuntu 18.10. It runs into errors as it can not write the temporary file it expects. It fails for error 2: No such file or directory. The privileges on `/tmp` are default.

I have read this is not a problem with Windows or Mac OS for the reason that it would not be restricted in this way.

How do I solve this? Should I configure my system differently (preferred) or alter the code?

Edit:

The file in question is actually created, permissions are 
`-rwxrwxr-x  1 lucas lucas 51263 Apr 26 11:12 monalisa13902330713449850714bin*`

However, the the program cannot find it:

`monalisa.tools.tinv.TInvariantCalculator$InvokeProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/monalisa13902330713449850714bin" (in directory "/tmp"): error=2, No such file or directory`

The `/tmp` directory is determined correctly by `File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));`

The file is created here:

```java
    toolFile = FileUtils.extractResource("tinv_unix", "monalisa", "bin");
```

```java
    public static File extractResource(URL resource, String prefix,
            String suffix) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Extracting resource '" + resource.toString() + "'");
        File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);
```

Running `exec /tmp/[file name]` returns the same error.

Comment: Please add the part of the code where the file is set and the write operation happens. Generally you should use `java.io.tmpdir` for temporary files which can be `/tmp` on some systems.

Comment: Just to be sure: the asterisk at the end of what looks like a partial output of `ls` is because of [this](https://superuser.com/q/178786/432690), right? In the actual filename there is none, right? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, it is only because of ll